# "Человек дела, действия и результата"— грамотна ли фраза?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика

*Почему-то считается, что отец расстраивался, что его не наградили. Но у него не было по этому поводу никаких переживаний, потому что он не был честолюбивым. **Он был человек дела, действия и результата.** Хотя у него были и правительственные награды, и госпремии.*
[**Чернобыльская катастрофа**](http://www.mk.ru/social/2017/04/25/kak-ubivali-akademika-legasova-kotoryy-provel-sobstvennoe-rassledovanie-chernobylskoy-katastrofy.html)

Фраза из интервью - "человек дела, действия и результата" - показалась мне *тавтологичной по смыслу*. Возможно, здесь есть какой-то особенный прием, которого я не ощущаю?
А как видите Вы: грамотна ли фраза?

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаемая редакция: **Он был человек дела, то есть человек действия и результата.**

**Дело** обычно включает в себя **действие**, доведенное до нужного **результата**, а в приведенном примере эти слова могут восприниматься как однородный ряд.

Если даже  сочетание "действия и результата" является обособленным пояснением, то в структуре данного предложения это не очевидно.

Comment: Простите, дело ведь не в редактировании! Статья УЖЕ есть в газете с крупным тиражом(ссылка имеется). Меня заинтересовал вопрос: есть ли во фразе "неправильность" или "относительная" тавтология? Или - если не тавтология - другой какой-то литературный приём?

Comment: Если я предлагаю редакцию, значит, фраза мне кажется неправильной. Почему - я объяснила: дело, действие и результат не могут, с моей точки зрения, составлять однородный ряд (дело состоит из действия и результата). Человек дела - это человек действия, причем результативного.

Comment: А разве запятой недостаточно, чтобы считать что "человек действия и результата" - это пояснение к "человеку дела"?

Comment: В этом случае получается одинаковая запись разных конструкций, но воспринимается такая запись как однородный ряд.